# Unable to start debugging on the web server. The Visual Studio 2019 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, remote-debugging

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Preview on Windows 10 pro. My project (source code) is https://github.com/smartstoreag/SmartStoreNET/tree/3.x/src . I press <kbd>F5</kbd> to see result, but I catch error

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The Visual Studio 2019
>   Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the
>   remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing
>   communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance
>   on configuring remote debugging.

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to set up the website in IIS, and possibly add an entry to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Check the project properties to see what URL needs to be set up.

Alternatively, you could try running in IIS Express instead of IIS.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the related site(s) in IIS tied to my solution were "stopped" in IIS. Once I went into IIS and "started" them, this debug error went away.